# Extension: Can I negotiate original offer if I have other offer from different company?

Tags: salary, negotiation, job-offer

This question is a direct and specific extension of [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/80736/55100) question that I had posted few days ago and received very good suggestions.

Now I have an offer from another company worth $(X+10)k but I am interested in working for the first company (that is the one that offered me $(X+5)). I have got written offer letters from both companies.

Can I negotiate with the first company to get what the second company is offering me? I do not want to do this at risk of rescinding the current $(X + 5) offer.

Secondly, both the offer letters say that they want me to accept and sign the offers if acceptable at my 'earliest'. How much time do I really have before I have to accept the offer? The interview process took almost 3-4 weeks for both the companies so I expect them to be patient while I make a decision but I'm not sure whether the candidates do have such choice.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9338/how-to-use-multiple-offers-to-negotiate-a-higher-salary

Comment: The interview process could have taken 3-4 weeks because they needed to interview several candidates before deciding to whom to make offers. Once they've _made_ that decision, and extended an offer (to you), they're quite likely not to want to hang around (if you don't accept in a timely manner, the chances are there's a "close second" waiting in the wings).

Comment: Is one week acceptable?

Comment: My gut feeling is that one week is more "_the longest you could push it_", especially since you have both offers (i.e. you aren't waiting for another company to make an offer before you decide).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I negotiate with the first company to get what the second company is offering me?

You can negotiate. Whether this would be successful or not can't be predicted.

> I do not want to do this at risk of rescinding the current $(X + 5) offer.

This can't be guaranteed. This would depend on how desperate the company is, they may have no pressing needs or the hiring manager is a stickler of ethics and may get offended. Rescinding an offer is multi step process, the offer letter should state till when the offer is good; else the company would give you a notice to accept the offer or reject it. The time allowance would depend on the jurisdiction.